# Ternary condition in c# logic not working as desired

Tags: c#

I have written a ternary condition in c# which isnt evaluating correctly. I am checking if both condition satisfy then it should return true otherwise false. At the moment it is returning true even if one condition fails. So even if the docType is Flashnotes is true, the canView is setting to true. Consider this IoC.Resolve().Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments") 
 always returning true and docType may or may not return true

```
doc.canView = IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>().Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments") ==
                                  AuthAccessLevel.Full &&  i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int) DocumentType.FlashNotes ||
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.CallMeetingNotes || 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.OtherNotes || 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.TearSheet
                        ? true
                        : false;
```

Comment: Enclose everything after `&&` in parentheses (until right before `?`).

Comment: If this is the desired use and not just a debugging effort then why are you assigning true/false in this fashion and not just doing a direct assignment based on the evaluation?

Comment: You don't really need a ternary for a `bool` evaluation like that. It's like saying `bool result = (someValue == someOtherValue) ? true : false;`, which can be simplified to `bool result = (someValue == someOtherValue);`

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood this correctly one of the `i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID` consditions must equate to `true`? Add parenthesis to equate that first.

```
doc.canView = IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>().Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments") ==
                              AuthAccessLevel.Full &&  (i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int) DocumentType.FlashNotes ||
                                                       i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.CallMeetingNotes || 
                                                       i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.OtherNotes || 
                                                       i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.TearSheet)
```

Also there's no need for the true or false as it's already a bool.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do can be simplified into something like this:

```
var rejectedTypes = new[] { DocumentType.FlashNotes, DocumentType.CallMeetingNotes,
                            DocumentType.OtherNotes, DocumentType.TearSheet }.Cast<int>();
var accessLevel = IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>()
                     .Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments");
doc.canView = ((accessLevel == AuthAccessLevel.Full) &&
               !rejectedTypes.Contains(i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mistake in the logic here. Try:

```
doc.canView = IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>().Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments") ==
                                  AuthAccessLevel.Full &&  !(i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int) DocumentType.FlashNotes ||
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.CallMeetingNotes || 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.OtherNotes || 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID == (int)DocumentType.TearSheet);
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer

Comment: The only change is I dont need to return true or false as suggested by others

Comment: Erm,  no it isn't. DeMorgan’s Theorem says !A & !B is equivalent to !(A | B). Wesley would have had to convert his i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID terms to && to be the same.

Answer (score -1):

It's an order of operations problem.  You can find out more about ordering it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
doc.canView = IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>().Authorize("Put", "ManageDocuments") ==
                                  AuthAccessLevel.Full &&  (i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int) DocumentType.FlashNotes &&
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.CallMeetingNotes && 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.OtherNotes && 
                                                           i.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID != (int)DocumentType.TearSheet) 
                        ? true // Redundant code but included to show ternary operator
                        : false;
```

Comment: I had tried this but it still returns true when the docType is FlashNotes

Comment: @Tom You are aware that `||` means "OR", right? You probably want to replace every instance of `||` with `&&`.

Comment: You are right. I need to && for everyinstance of ||